# macOS xargs will not open app found by mdfind and grep

Tags: macos, terminal, grep, xargs, mdfind

I'm looking for one command that find path and open all of .app with only change app name in Terminal.

I tried :

```
mdfind "calendar.app" "kind:app" | grep -v '/Users/' | xargs open
```

Work well with calendar, safari, calculator --> find and open .app

But when i tried .app with space, it doesn't work:

```
mdfind "Google Chrome.app" "kind:app" | grep -v '/Users/' | xargs open
```

The files /Applications/Google and /Users/Simon/Chrome.app do not exist.

I tried with -0, \ but not work

Can u help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the actual problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title just echoes information already available in the tags and provides no useful information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be useful to a future site user who is scanning through a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem, and your current title does not do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `mdfind` returns `/Applications/Google Chrome.app`, a name containing a space, you need to wrap it in quotes before you pass it to `xargs`.

```sh
mdfind "Google Chrome.app" "kind:app" | grep -v '/Users/' | awk '{print "\x27" $0 "\x27" }' | xargs open
```

Like this, `awk` will print a single quote (`\x27`) before and after the string, resulting in: `'/Applications/Google Chrome.app'`. Now, `xargs` will understand this input properly.